# Как проверять отрицание в SASS (SCSS)?

Tags: sass, scss

Создал тестовый mixin для демонстрации и задал ему условие на присутствие $arg:

```
@mixin test($arg) {
    @if($arg) {
        @error $arg;
    }
}
```

Если $arg приходит, то проверка проходит. Пробую сделать проверку на отрицание $arg и получаю ошибку синтаксиса:

```
@mixin test($arg) {
    @if(!$arg) {
        @error $arg;
    }
}
```

Как правильно проверять отрицание в SASS (SCSS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:

```
@mixin test($arg) {
  @if(not $arg) {
    @error $arg;
   }
}
```